# Would automated builds of a game violate single-user licenses on assets?

Tags: licensing

I have access to a number of sound effect libraries via a personal single-user commercial license, allowing one backup copy each (which I am understanding GitHub to count as, purely out of caution) file without needing to be "synchronized" with some other form of media, in which case I have unlimited use. I would like to run automated builds and unit tests, but I'm worried about whether this would be a violation of the single-user licensing since the assets would be present on another machine in order to be built.

Sound synchronization in games seems particularly ambiguous to me. What counts as synchronization when a sound must be kept in some sort of raw format and could be "synchronized" at any point in gameplay? Does having all your sound effects in the project tree count as synchronization or does it need to be in a packed asset file?

**Am I legally allowed to run automated builds on another system or would it violate single-user audio library licenses?**

For my particular project, the commercial sounds I am using have been purchased through Sonniss. ([Sonniss license](https://sonniss.com/sound-effects-licensing/))

Answer (score 2):

Specifically with regard to the Sonniss license, it includes the following:

> **Rights Granted**
>
> d) Licensee may transfer the licensed sound effects to one local hard drive and also make one additional backup copy for personal use. This license does not allow you to upload the sound effects to a network-drive, server or make copies available to other unlicensed users.

and

> **Restrictions**
>
> d) Licensee must be the sole editor, otherwise a multi-user license will be required. Purchasing a multi-user license will allow you to use the sound effects libraries on more than one workstation and by multiple people on your production team. A multi-user license is more commonly known in the industry as a “network” or “site” license. Click here for more information.

I would interpret this as a "no" with regard to being allowed to include an automated process, as this is not on your local hard disk, it is **not** a backup copy (it would be an active copy involved in a process), and it is **not** on a local drive - you will need a more permissive license.

You may be able to get a clarification from the copyright holder as to whether your specific use is acceptable under their license, but right now I would say that the license does not allow it.

As to your more general question about single user licenses and automated processes - it would very much depend on the license I am afraid, so no general answer can be given.